# How to make a replica list in SharePoint online?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have two list "ParentList" and "ChildList" in SharePoint online. I want the ChildList list to be with same content as ParentList. All the operations like item add, delete etc performing in ParentList should reflect in the ChildList. No operations are performing in the ChildList. ChildList should be act just like a view in the list.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the item from 'parentList' simply create a new View:

1. ListSettings->Create view [under view header]).
2. Select columns you want to display in that view.
3. Then go to anypage where you want to show this view.
4. Edit page and `Insert->AppPart` choose 'ParentList' & select 'View' in the drop down and click OK.

---

However, If you want to stick with replica list concept then you need to create a simple workflow for 'ParentList' using SharePoint designer:

1. Add 'Copy item' action and configure the parameters it will automatically copy `item` to 'ChildList'.
2. Configure 'Startup options' to 'Start workflow automatically for both created/changed'.
3. Then hit 'Check for errors' and 'Publish'

Comment: I have implemented it by workflow using designer. Thanks.